# Display python print() in tkinter textbox

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to display, in live, the python print() statement of a keylogger to the textbox of tkinter.

So far, I can either use the window or the keyboard logger that writes to console (spyder) with print() commands, but not both at the same time.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tkinter
import tkinter.scrolledtext
from pynput import keyboard


def on_press(key):
    try:
        print('Alphanumeric key pressed: {0} '.format(key.char))
    except AttributeError:
        print('Special key pressed: {0}'.format(key))

def on_release(key):
    print('Key released: {0}'.format(key))
    # Stop the listener
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        return False


# Main window
main = tkinter.Tk()
main.title('keyboad Logger')
main.geometry('500x400')


# Scrollable Textbox
txt = tkinter.scrolledtext.ScrolledText(main, width = 40, height = 30)

# Insert into Textbox
txt.insert(tkinter.END, "Some text here")

txt.pack()

# main.mainloop()

# Collect events until released
with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
       listener.join()
```

Comment: I cannot comprehend the question. Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: great, first start by removing all of the `print()` functions and replace them with `<tkinter.Text>.insert()` methods (where `<tkinter.Text>` is the instance of Your Text widget)

Comment: You do not need to use pynput, tkinter has a option to detect key. Also, why have you commented the root.mainloop

Comment: And if you have a scrolled text, why do you need to detect key press using other modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pynput listener runs in another thread, so when you join that thread, the tkinter thread is blocked. Therefore your GUI doesn't show up. This also creates another problem, as tkinter does not work with multiple threads, so there needs to be a way to communicate between the listener thread and the tkinter thread. You also can't use `.join()` on the thread, as this will block the tkinter one.

```
def on_press(key, print_list):
    try:
        print_list.append('Alphanumeric key pressed: {0} '.format(key.char))
    except AttributeError:
        print_list.append('Special key pressed: {0}'.format(key))

def on_release(key, print_list):
    print_list.append('Key released: {0}'.format(key))
    print(print_list)
    # Stop the listener
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        return False

def check_print():
    global print_list
    if print_list != []:
        for item in print_list:
            txt.insert(tkinter.END, item + "\n")
        print_list = []
    main.after(100, check_print)

# Main window
main = tkinter.Tk()
main.title('keyboad Logger')
main.geometry('500x400')


# Scrollable Textbox
print_list = []
txt = tkinter.scrolledtext.ScrolledText(main, width = 40, height = 30)

# Insert into Textbox
txt.insert(tkinter.END, "Some text here")

txt.pack()

# Collect events until released
listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=lambda key: on_press(key, print_list), on_release=lambda key: on_release(key, print_list), supress = True)
listener.start()
check_print()
main.mainloop()
```

To solve the first problem, I've changed how your listener thread works. Now instead of joining the thread, which would block the GUI, we just start the thread in the background using `.start()`. In order to communicate between the two threads, I've added a list called `print_list`. This is passed from the main program to the listener thread as an argument for `on_press` and `on_release`. Then when something would have been printed, it is now appended to the list. Now the keys are being logged, but the GUI does not show it yet, so I added the `check_print` function. This is first called after the listener thread starts, then is called by itself every 100ms to check `print_list`. If it has something in it, it is inserted into the text widget and then set to empty. The program now works as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much for that prompt and working answer. And BIG thx for the explanation of the problem!

Comment: Glad I could help :)